# How to read Class Objects / Functions when passed as a param?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm current working with Discord's Gateway and sockets to create something similar to `discord.js` and to make it easier for a new user to use the package i'm making i would like them to view the `Message` class objects and functions when passed as a param. I have been unsuccessful in all of my attempts at this.

**Example from `Discord.js`:**

[image: Discord.js's Example]

**Example from `My Package`:**

[image: My Example]

**My `.on()` Code:**

```js
/**
 * client.on() [ when received certain operation from discord's gateway ]
 * @param {OPERATION} operation 
 * @param {FUNCTION} func 
 */
on(operation, func) {

    ws.on('message', (data) => {
        let payload = JSON.parse(data)
        const {t, event, op, d} = payload

        // OPERATION => operation
        operation = operation.toLowerCase();

        // if op => message
        switch(operation) {
            case "message": {
                switch(t) {
                    case "MESSAGE_CREATE":
                        // message build
                        let message = new Message().init(d, this.token)
                        return func(message)
                        //          ^^^^^^^ this is where message is passed
                    }
            }
        }
        
        })

}
```

**My `Message.init()` Code:**

```js
init(d, token) {

    this.content = d.content
    this.channel = {
        id: d.channel_id,
        send: (content) => {
            sendMessage(d.channel_id, token, content)
        }
    }
    this.author = {
        bot: d.author.bot ? d.author.bot : false,
        username: d.author.username,
        tag: `${d.author.username}#${d.author.discriminator}`,
        identifier: d.author.discriminator,
        id: d.author.id,
        avatar: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${d.author.id}/${d.author.avatar}.gif` // avatar image
    }
    this.guild = {
        id: d.guild_id
    }
    this.timestamp = d.timestamp

    return this

}
```

I've looked something like this up and couldn't find anything specific to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Discord is probably written in Typescript. If you want such Intellisense support you should write in typescript

Comment: So you're asking how to show the useful stuff first inside the window that pops up when you type a dot after an object? (this comment is supposed to illustrate how to ask this question without knowing the word "intellisense")

Comment: @ChrisG the `message` property is type `message: any` and i'm looking of it to be type `message: Message`

Comment: Yeah, obviously. Do you know how to write Typescript?

Comment: have not tried it much, it seems that discord.js does use typescript but not for their client class. would typescript still show the type of the param in a vanilla js project when installed?

Comment: They're using it. There are type definitions for the client and their methods too. Your IDE just fetches these types when you working with your "vanilla" JavaScript code.

Comment: @bill.gates Discord.js is (still) written in javascript [source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/main/packages/discord.js) But they provide support for typescript with some separate .d.ts files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell jsdoc what arguments your function accept. While `FUNCTION` works generically you need to be more specific:

```
/**
 * client.on() [ when received certain operation from discord's gateway ]
 * @param {OPERATION} operation 
 * @param {(message:Message) => void} func 
 */
```

This says that the second argument is a function that returns nothing (`void`) and has a `Message` object as its argument. Presumably then you will have a `Message` class/constructor somewhere in your project.

Comment: Note: This example will work only for `message` event. If OP will need to implement different events with different callback parameters then he will be unable to do so with JSDoc.

Comment: @koloml Typescript types (what is supported by jsdoc) supports union types. You can simply specify `(Message|Other|AnotherOne) => void`

Comment: Union types are working fine, yes. But not the complicated features like `keyof` and generics. In DiscordJS there is a `type` with all available event names (keys) and the list of the arguments which are sent to the callback (values). So when you type in specific event name, IDE will fetch what is being sent back.

Comment: Without [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L3839-L3923) and [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/86d8fbc023e3925e8f86799d6ebf2d423f7bf2ec/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L191) OP will unable to make this work for different events.

Comment: this worked when changing it to `@param {(message:Message) => void} func ` thanks @slebetman

Comment: @koloml i made a different project using `ts` and tried implementing that and it has not worked for me, current with my js project im using functions like `on_ready()` and `on_message()` but i would like to use the EventEmitter for this, any more information you could give would be appreciated :)

Comment: @gavin It's kinda hard to explain, especially in the comments. But the general thing is: you should create the interface where keys are names of the events and values are arrays with attributes for the callback function. And then, like in example from `discord.js`, you just using generics to tell IDE which event is used.

Comment: Maybe I should just write the answer with detailed information then.

Comment: @koloml thank you, but i switched the whole project to typescript and starting using a package called tsee that kinda does the whole event emitter types for me

Comment: @koloml without you pointing those bits of code out i wouldn’t have fully understand what need to happen for this to work

Comment: @gavin well, typescript is much better for such features. Glad to help you finding The Better™ solution.

Answer (score 0):

Document your code using jsdoc. you'll probably want to read more about it at https://jsdoc.app/

Once you'll have that vscode (and other supported IDEs) will do the rest of the "magic"